# How to block a server by domain name from attacking a website

Tags: webserver

I'm having trouble with another website stealing all my blog content. I know that happens all the time, but this new attack is taking down my server.

Looking at my access logs I see he is hitting me from multiple IP address. I can't block them all. Wondering how to block by domain name.

I have full access to my server so I would like to block with iptables, but not sure that is possible.

Also, how do I shut them down, it's a private registration with godaddy. I called them but no help at all.

Comment: might be better answered on server fault?

Comment: Do all the IP addresses resolve to the same domain?

Comment: Stealing your content? That's copyright infringement. Another piece of ammo for your battle. Good luck!

Comment: there are tons of websites that steal content... with rss feeds all you content can be easily posted on other blogs.

Answer (score 0):

probably belongs on superuser.com, BUT in code, you could do a quick IP hash map that keeps a running count of visits by IP in the last 10 minutes, then 404's if there are over X number of them. You could then log out the IP's that you are 404ing to, and dump them into iptables to block.

Comment: They all resolve to the same domain cheaps1.info
a google search found this:
http://www.threatexpert.com/report.aspx?md5=ccc3ee3459dafdfab05fc5ea394bac4b

I added cheaps1.info to my hosts.deny file and the problem seems to have stopped for now